# How to make my PC become an "psudo/fake" external display for android phone via USB ports (without using any USB to HDMI dongles)

Tags: usb, linux, windows, hdmi

I want my Android phone to recognize my PC as its external display (psuedo/fake or virtual displays) via USB connection (USB-C - USB-A cable or TCP connection) without using any USB to HDMI dongles or wifi display like miracast either.

I think I need to find or write the app/software or driver on PC side which have USB protocol like any real USB-C to HDMI display to communicate with the phone. Do you have any suggestion or guidelines?

Thanks,

Comment: I would be surprised if common USB chips used in a PC would support working in USB client mode or receive HDMI signals (USB alternate mode), at least not under Windows.

Comment: I am flagging it as off topic. Its also posted on Software Recommendations. Please dont multi post.

Comment: Reposted on [Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1799055/356789) and [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87533/520)

Answer (score -1):

You could use a vncviewer/TeamViewer program... allows both screen and some controls to control the system...

You would set server on android since its the one you want displayed, then set client on pc. Newer phones even have a default program called Android dex, it also allows screen sharing properties